# Cinema 4D. Can't make the Inner Extrude of multiple polygons evenly

Tags: polygon, cinema-4d

When I'm trying to make inner extrude of multiple polygons it extruded them unevenly. I can see that coordinates are slightly moving as well. Please help to understand how to solve this. See the image below.

[image: uneven inner extrusion in Cinema 4D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. To solve this you need to set the Offset Variation to zero to prevent randomization. See the image attached.

[image]